# PyautoGUI doesn't give out coordinates for one function while works for another

Tags: python, automation, scripting, pyautogui

I am working on a script that accepts the game of league of legends automatically, then moves to the chat dialogue to call the lane. This worked fine for the `click_accept()` function, prints out the `x`,`y` coordinates perfectly. However the `print(pos.x/2,pos.y/2)` line for `click_chat_dialog()` gives me the following error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'x'`

Here is my code:

```py
import pyautogui, time, os, logging, sys, random, copy

def imPath(filename):
    return os.path.join('images', filename)


def click_accept():
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(imPath('accept_button.png'), confidence=0.8) != None:
        pos = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(imPath('accept_button.png'))
        print(pos.x/2,pos.y/2)
        pyautogui.moveTo(pos.x/2,pos.y/2)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pyautogui.click(pos.x/2,pos.y/2)

def click_chat_dialog():
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(imPath('chat_dialog.png'), confidence=0.6) != None:
        pos = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(imPath('chat_dialog.png'))
        print(pos.x/2,pos.y/2)
        pyautogui.moveTo(pos.x/2,pos.y/2)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pyautogui.click(pos.x/2,pos.y/2)



while 1:
    click_accept()
    click_chat_dialog()
```

Here are the images I am using:

Accept Button - https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCIvQ.png

Chat Dialogue - https://i.stack.imgur.com/BifMP.png

Accept Screen - https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCWsO.jpg

Chat Screen - https://i.imgur.com/LfZQCnR.png

Answer (score 0):

NoneType is returned when PyAutoGUI cannot find what you are looking for. I see that you tested to see if the object could be found, but another exception handling may be required for locatecenter...without seeing the actual input (image) of what you are looking for that's about as much as I could say.

```
import pyautogui, time, os, logging, sys, random, copy

def imPath(filename):
    return os.path.join('images', filename)


def click_accept():
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(imPath('accept_button.png'), confidence=0.8) != None:
        pos = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(imPath('accept_button.png'))
        print(pos.x/2,pos.y/2)
        pyautogui.moveTo(pos.x/2,pos.y/2)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pyautogui.click(pos.x/2,pos.y/2)

def click_chat_dialog():
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(imPath('chat_dialog.png'), confidence=0.6) != None:
        try:
            pos = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(imPath('chat_dialog.png'))
        except TypeError:
            #perform some other action because pos was not found..
        print(pos.x/2,pos.y/2)
        pyautogui.moveTo(pos.x/2,pos.y/2)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pyautogui.click(pos.x/2,pos.y/2)



while 1:
    click_accept()
    click_chat_dialog()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I do have images linked in my question. While accept button gives out coordinates perfectly on the image Accept Screen, the problem arises when I try to get coordinates for Chat Dialogue on the Chat Screen image. I can confirm that python is able to locate the chat dialogue on chat screen image, but still pops out the coordinates as None.

Comment: Nice project. I am wondering: is the chat dialog image detailed enough so that when the algorithm to fit it finds it's target, it would be with a high enough confidence? 

I think you are trying to minimize the image so that you can click right on it, but perhaps you could make the image for chat dialog larger (without including the unique "XXX joined the lobby" imagery above? the concept is similar to trying to orient a circle vs orienting a very orientable object like a scalene triangle. And instead of pos.x/y pos.x/y-some offset to land in the correct location?

Comment: Thanks for the input, yes I figured it could be because of the size of the chat dialogue image that I am facing the issue, will try with a larger image. Thanks for the input.